# Star Rating Js + html with symfony

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project with symfony 4. I want to implement a star rating system. I display 5 stars in each row in a table. I have two problems, one is more important than the other.

So the first issue is that I want to be able to retrieve the value of the star I selected. If I select 5 stars, I want to get that value back in my entity controller.

The second issue is that, currently, let's say I have 5 items in my table, so 5 rows. Currently, if I select 5 stars in one row it's selected for all rows and I can't select another value anymore. So, it's global or something.

Here is the javascript I'm using:

```
<script>
    const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
    let check = false;
    stars.forEach(star => {
        star.addEventListener('mouseover', selectStars);
        star.addEventListener('mouseleave', unselectStars);
        star.addEventListener('click', activeSelect);
    })

    function selectStars(e) {
        const data = e.target;
        const etoiles = priviousSiblings(data);
        if (!check) {
            etoiles.forEach(etoile => {
                etoile.classList.add('hover');
            })
        }

    }

    function unselectStars(e) {
        const data = e.target;
        const etoiles = priviousSiblings(data);
        if (!check) {
            etoiles.forEach(etoile => {
                etoile.classList.remove('hover');
            })
        }
    }

    function activeSelect(e) {
        if (!check) {
            check = true;
            document.querySelector('.note').innerHTML = 'Note ' + e.target.dataset.note;
        }
    }

    function priviousSiblings(data) {
        let values = [data];
        while (data === data.previousSibling) {
            if (data.nodeName === 'I') {
                values.push(data);
            }
        }
        return values;
    }
</script>
```

And Here is the twig.html I'm displaying:

```
<td>
    <i class="star" data-note="1">&#9733;</i>
    <i class="star" data-note="2">&#9733;</i>
    <i class="star" data-note="3">&#9733;</i>
    <i class="star" data-note="4">&#9733;</i>
    <i class="star" data-note="5">&#9733;</i>
    <i class="note">Note:</i>
</td>
```

I want to be able to retrieve the value once I made a selection, and to have a different selection for each row I have.

Comment: Seems like if `check` is `true`, you are not doing anything during mouseover/mouseleave. Could you try adding `else` conditions inside `selectStars` and `unselectStars` functions?

Comment: Check is true yes. What should I be doing?

Comment: You could do something like this. For example, in selectStars, you may add something like `else { etoiles.forEach(etoile => { etoile.classList.remove('hover'); }) }`. And also add something similar to the other function `unselectStars`

Comment: Still the same, problem, once I select a rating in one row, I can't can no longer select in other rows. If I hover over them nothing happens and I can't select a rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the "mouseover" and "mouseleave" event handlers - `selectStars` and `unselectStars`. In "selectStars", you are adding the class to only one star. And in "unselectStars", you were not resetting, or applying the "remove" class method to other stars.

Anyway, here is how I have achieved what you are trying to do:

```js
const ratings = document.querySelectorAll('.rating');
ratings.forEach(rating =>
  rating.addEventListener('mouseleave', ratingHandler)
);

const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.rating .star');
stars.forEach(star => {
  star.addEventListener('mouseover', starSelection);
  star.addEventListener('mouseleave', starSelection);
  star.addEventListener('click', activeSelect);
});

function ratingHandler(e) {
  const childStars = e.target.children;
  for(let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
    const star = childStars.item(i)
    if (star.dataset.checked === "true") {
      star.classList.add('hover');
    }
    else {
      star.classList.remove('hover');
    }
  }
}

function starSelection(e) {
  const parent = e.target.parentElement
  const childStars = parent.children;
  const dataset = e.target.dataset;
  const note = +dataset.note; // Convert note (string) to note (number)
  for (let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
    const star = childStars.item(i)
    if (+star.dataset.note > note) {
      star.classList.remove('hover');
    } else {
      star.classList.add('hover');
    }
  }
}

function activeSelect(e) {
  const parent = e.target.parentElement
  const childStars = parent.children;
  const dataset = e.target.dataset;
  const note = +dataset.note; // Convert note (string) to note (number)
  for (let i = 0; i < childStars.length; i++) {
    const star = childStars.item(i)
    if (+star.dataset.note > note) {
      star.classList.remove('hover');
      star.dataset.checked = "false";
    } else {
      star.classList.add('hover');
      star.dataset.checked = "true";
    }
  }

  const noteTextElement = parent.parentElement.lastElementChild.children.item(0)
  noteTextElement.innerText = `Note: ${note}`;
}
```

You might notice I have a `.rating` class component. This is a `div` which I have created to hold all these "stars". Here is a link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/andys-codepen/pen/MWrxGxb) I have created. Feel free to play around with it.

And as a note, please provide codepen (or any other) demos so that we can debug a bit better and faster.

I hope the codepen link would help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank u I tested it and it seems to solve the issue of not being able to select a rating more than once, but stars are still selected globally, meaning if I have 3 rows, if I hover over one row's stars it's as if I hovered over all of them, the animation happens for all the stars in all the rows. 
And the value is also global, for all the stars in all the rows. Not quite sure how to solve that

Comment: Could you create a codepen of your code, and post the link here? It would be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: I can't really post it to codepen because it's twig code that contains stuff about my symfony entities so it won't work. I'll try to explain as best I can, I have a controller that returns an array of objects that get displayed in a table an object per row. I want to have a star rating with each row. Using your code, I can keep selecting as ratings as many times as I want. 

Let's say I have 5 entries in my table, meaning 5 rows. I get 5 stars in each row. Now when I select stars 3 in the first row for example, they are automatically selected in all rows as well. That's the issue I'm facing.

Comment: @MoudhafferBouallegui I have updated my codepen. I think it now solves the problem that you are pointing out.

Comment: Thank you so much now it's working the way I want it. You're a life saver! Now, all that's left is how I can get the value I selected associated with the entity in that row. I realize this is a vague or big question to ask without you knowing what my entities and controllers look like so I'd just ask you to point me in the right direction. I want to retrieve the selected value from the stars and affect that value to an attribute in my entity and save that value in my database in the entity's table

Comment: As you can see, you are already grabbing the rating value which is the value of `note` at the end of `activeSelect` function. Just pass that on to your apis (or any other function or entitites).